# How to solve this differential equation: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^3+y^2}{2xy}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using homogeneous, it's changed to $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac1{2v}+\dfrac v{2x}$ where $v=\dfrac yx$.

I'm not sure how to solve this further on. I tried using symbol but the steps seem to be too complicated to be implemented in their calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\frac{2yy'}{x}-\frac{y^2}{x^2}=x$. Integrating: $\frac{y^2}{x}=\frac{1}{2}x^2+C$. So $y=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}x^3+Cx}$.